# Replace cos^..(...) by (cos(...))^

Tags: r, string

I run WolframAlpha through R
[Wolfram Alpha API from R](https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/a8bf2033f3eda527fa61)

My problem is, that I need to convert wolfram output to R expression.
I have added "*" where it's needed, there's another issue - converting of goniometric functions.

Example:

*I have:* cos^3(5 + 2*x)

*I need to get:* (cos(5 + 2*x))^3

Could somebody give me a hint how to achieve the expression? Or is there any package for conversion? Or does somebody suggest any other way?

**SOLUTION** by @G. Grothendieck

```
sub("(sin|cos|tan)\\^(\\(?-?\\d+\\)?)", "(function(x) \\1(x)^\\2)", 'cos^3(5 + 2*x)')
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a function called `cos^3`, insert backticks into the original string around it and evaluate.

```
`cos^3` <- function(x) cos(x)^3
s <- sub("cos^3", "`cos^3`", input_string, fixed = TRUE)  # `cos^3`(5 + 2*x)

x <- .5  # test value for x
eval(parse(text = s))
## [1] 0.8852069
```

This could be generalized a bit if need be like this:

```
input_string <- "cos^(3)(5+2*x)"
sub("(sin|cos|tan)\\^(\\(?-?\\d+\\)?)", "(function(x) \\1(x)^\\2)", input_string)
## [1] "(function(x) cos(x)^(3))(5+2*x)"
```

Comment: Really handy solution, Thank you

Comment: Can you complete the regex for case with parenthesis: `cos^(-1)(x)` ?
(I have tried but couldn't manage)

Comment: See last example, now revised.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have the original formula as a string and want to evaluate it in R (with the modified syntax).  You can change the formula using `sub` and then evaluate it using `parse` and `eval`.

```
F1 = "cos^3(5 + 2*x)"
F2 = sub("(.*)(\\^\\d)(.*)", "\\1\\3\\2", F1)
F2
[1] "cos(5 + 2*x)^3"

x = 1:4
eval(parse(text=F2))
[1]  4.284944e-01 -7.563824e-01  8.668527e-08  7.472458e-01
```

Comment: I did not know how to set this part `"(.*)(\\^\\d)(.*)", "\\1\\3\\2"`. Another steps was easy to find. Thanks

Comment: Can you write it in general form? To convert cos^XX(YY)

Comment: The current form does that for any YY and for any number XX.  Do you need this to work where XX is also a formula?

Comment: Almost certainly not, but for example, it does not work for: `cos^(-1)(5 + 2*x)` nor `cos^2(5 + 2*x^3)`

Comment: You are right. My expression will not work for those cases. Handling completely general expressions of the form `Function^Expressin1(Expression2)` where Expression1 and Expression2 are arbitrary expressions including powers and parentheses is probably too complicated for these simple substitutions.  You would need to parse the expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to your specific case, which should help getting started on a more general solution (this will work for strings of the form `'cos^X(Y)'` where `X` is some digits and `Y` is an arithmetic expression):

```
input_string <- 'cos^3(5 + 2*x)'
desired_output_string <- '(cos(5 + 2*x))^3'

convert_string <- function(s){
  return(gsub('(cos)(\\^\\d+)(\\([a-z0-9+* ]+\\))', '(\\1\\3)\\2', s))
}

output_string <- convert_string(input_string)

if (output_string == desired_output_string){
  message('the output matches!') 
} else { message('try again </3') }
```

And then if you need to actually evaluate the string, you can use `eval(parse(text=output_string))`, making sure that all variables it contains have values:

```
x <- 5
eval(parse(text=output_string))
## -0.4384354
```